# Как используется csrf токен ставленный в мета тег?

Tags: php, html, laravel, csrf

Нужно изменить код написанный не мной,

В коде есть мета тег

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

и есть форма с LARAVEL Blade  директивой

```
@csrf
```

Хочу понять в чем смысл использования мета тега в коде, *какую функциональность она добавляет*?

Если есть ссылки, пожалуйста вставьте их вместе с ответом.

Comment: https://laravel.ru/posts/751#uw751-x-csrf-token

Answer (score 0):

Судя по документации в laravel отстутсвует предустановленная директива `@csrf`, поэтому она определена в каком-либо сервис-провайдере (подробнее http://laravel.su/docs/5.4/blade#extending-blade ).
Но прямой ответ на твой вопрос зачем нужен этот тег - это защита от подделки межсайтовых запросов http://laravel.su/docs/5.4/csrf